# Create statically linked libraries for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, static-linking

A friend and I are creating an iPhone app together. He's programming the user interface and I'm creating the backend photo-manipulation algorithms. In this respect I was wondering, is it possible to create a library in i.e. [Mono Touch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) (or something similar) that he could include in Xcode? The library would take one or more input photos, and return a processed image.

Are there alternatives to Mono Touch?

Comment: Is Objective-c or C an option?

Comment: It is, but I was hoping to be able to use C#, since I'm much better at this language.

Comment: there are some other questions out there about consuming MT code from Obj-C - I think the bottom line is NO.  As I understand it the simple answer is that Obj-C does not understand the C# type system.

Comment: Ok, but since it all gets compiled down to a common binary format, should it matter whether the written language is C#, Objective-C, or any other language at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Cocoa Touch Static Library project template included in Xcode. You can use that to create your static library.

Comment: Objective-C, C, C++. Your question *is* tagged [tag:objective-c].

Comment: Absolutely. But I also said in my comments that I was hoping to find a C# alternative, which is why I mentioned Mono Touch several times in my question...